# Finding an orthonormal basis with only one vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthonormal

I'm programming a little thing to project things to my screen from a variable amount dimensions, and when I tried to implement the ability to move the origin and rotate the direction looked in strange things started happening.

As a starting point I have one polar vector, the screen vector (in my program it defines how far the screen is from the origin and in which direction it is pointing).
In my initial attempt I just generated the basis by normalizing it and subtract $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ from the second index to get the second basis vector and repeat that for the others.
Then of course I convert all polar vectors to vectors.

What really happened was that the sphere that was loaded in collapsed into an ellipsoid when the vector was rotated.

In the attempt I'm trying to make I read up on a few other questions here, and most answers suggest use of the Gram-Schmidt algorithm.

The problem I'm having is I can't really think of a way to use that with only one starting vectors and end up with $n$ basis vectors.
A thing I was thinking of to do was to use random starting vectors, but I fear that will not be consistent.

How do I apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to only one vector to consistently get all basis vectors?

EDIT:
By the way, that basis is then used to transform the coordinates of the points into the observers frame.
If there's a way to avoid finding a basis for the vector and transforming the points that will do fine for me.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your subtraction of $\pi/2$?

Comment: $u_1$ = $v$, $u_2$ = $v - \frac{pi}{2}\hat{\phi_1}$ and so on.

Comment: I tried to do something like $u_1 = (x, y), u_2 = (-y, x)$

Comment: Actually, I can't see why this wouldn't work. Are you sure you are converting to Cartesian coordinates properly?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I am, although I'm using a bit of an awkward convention because of the variable number of dimensions it should work like: $x = r \cdot sin(\phi_1)sin(\phi_2), y = r \cdot cos(\phi_1)sin(\phi_2), z = r \cdot cos(\phi_2)$.

Comment: Note that just as I wrote that I noticed my method was flawed and actually did $x = r \cdot cos(\phi_1)sin(\phi_1)sin(\phi_2)$. Thanks for asking I guess, because I really believed that that was working :P

Answer (score 1):

*(Edit: simplified the whole procedure)*

What you need to do is find a basis that contains your starting vector $v\neq 0$. You can do it by starting with $S = \{ v,e_1, e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a known (orthonormed) basis. Apply Gram-Schmidt to this set. Note that $S$ is generating set for $\mathbb R^n$, but not a base. This doesn't matter, since Gram-Schmidt guarantees that the superflous vector will become zero. That way we obtain orthonormed base $\{v',e_1'\ldots,\hat e'_i,\ldots,e'_n\}$ (where $\hat e_i$ means that the vector is omitted).

Now, define matrix $O = [v'\ e_1'\ldots\ \hat e'_i\ \ldots\ e'_n]$ (where the vectors are written as columns in the standard orthonormal base $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$). Since columns of $O$ form orthonormal base for $\mathbb R^n$, the matrix $O$ is orthogonal. That means that it is either rotation or reflection. If $\det O = 1$, then $O$ is rotation that maps $e_1$ to $v$ and the rest of the standard orthonormal base to orthonormal base obtained by Gram-Schmidt, and we are done. If $\det O = -1$, switch any two columns in $O$ to obtain rotation.

Comment: I kind of doubt that that will be algorithmically possible without symbolic math.

Comment: Also I would like to hear why exactly subtracting pi/2 from one of the angles doesn't give a perpendicular vector.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by symbolic math, but of course this is algorithmically possible. It's basic linear algebra. Let me edit.

Comment: Symbolic math is a way of representing mathematical things as objects, a lot like wolframalpha does.

Comment: @S.Klumpers, you can always find some linear algebra package online.

Comment: Good point there.

Comment: But by doing this we get rid of the effects of rotation on the other basis vectors (I think). What I'm trying to do is to use the standard basis and rotate that in exactly the way the vector is rotated to get my basis.

Comment: @S.Klumpers, I believe the last edit remedies your troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Gram-Schmidt is one way to orthonormalize, but there is another that will work with a single vector: Householder QR decomposition. Here we are doing only one step, i.e. we transform the vector by a reflection.

Consider a vector $v$, with additional conditions $v\ne0$ (otherwise $v$ can't be part of a basis) and $v\ne \lambda e_1$ with $\lambda>0$ (otherwise we have a trivial orthonormal basis $v/\|v\|=e_1, e_2\dots, e_n$).

Let the vector $v'=\|v\|e_1=(|v\|,0,\dots,0)^T$, it's possible to transform $v$ into $v'$, using a reflection w.r.t the hyperplane orthogonal to the vector $u$, with $u=v-v'$. In the standard basis the matrix of this reflection is $H=I-2\dfrac{uu^T}{\|u\|^2}$. That is, $Hv=v'$.

It's easy to prove directly:

First, $\|u\|^2=(v-v')^T(v-v')=v^Tv-v^Tv'-v'^Tv+v'^Tv'=2v^Tv-2v'^Tv=2(v-v')^Tv$.

Then

$$Hv=v-\dfrac{2}{\|u\|^2}(v-v')(v-v')^Tv=v-(v-v')\frac{2(v-v')^Tv}{2(v-v')^Tv}=v'$$

And it's equally easy to check that $H$ is orthogonal and symmetric, therefore $H^2=I$ (which is expected, a reflection is an involution).

The symmetry is trivial, and

$$H^TH=H^2=(I-2\frac{uu^T}{\|u\|^2})(I-2\frac{uu^T}{\|u\|^2})=I-4\frac{uu^T}{\|u\|^2}+4\frac{u(u^Tu)u^T}{\|u\|^4}=I$$

Therefore, $Hv=v'$ implies that $Hv'=v$, or $\|v\| He_1=v$.

But we have then trivially an orthogonal basis such that its first vector is a multiple of $v$: just transform the orthogonal basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ by $H$, i.e. $H(e_1,\dots,e_n)=HI$, but that is $H$.

Therefore, the columns of $H$ are orthogonal and have norm $1$, and the first column of $H$ is $\dfrac{v}{\|v\|}$.

---

In general there are two possible reflections, w.r.t the hyperplanes orthogonal to $v-v'$ or $v+v'$. We can do the same construction with only the constraint $v\ne0$, by choosing $u=v+\mathrm{sign}(v_1) v'$, so that $u\ne0$ if $v=\lambda e_1$ with $\lambda>0$. It's usually what is done for the "true" QR decomposition, in order to avoid cancellation in the first element of $v+\mathrm{sign}(v_1) v'$.